# How can I reconnect a disconnected network drive on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, networking

When my computer comes out of Standby (S3) my permantent network shares are disconnected (in My Computer under Network Drives it says "disconnected network drive").

They do reconnect when I click them in an explorer, but I have timed backup scripts (Windows .cmd files) running which wake the computer and need to access one of those drives and which fail at file access.

Is there a way to reconnect such a drive from a Windows XP cmd file?

Answer (score 2):

possibly adding the relevant

```
net use X: \\server\share
```

commands to the scripts will be enough to refresh the connections

or, rewrite the scripts to use the UNC paths directly (I'm never sure if I believe the theory that this results in slower access than a mapped drive...)

Comment: I was hoping for a way where it wasn't necessary for the script to know the location of the mapped drive (i.e. to be able to just move \\server\share somewhere else in the future without having to update the scripts).   something like "net reopen x:" (I'm just making this up) or a clever trick to that end.